# Setting result from pgfmathifthenelse as variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

So I'm trying to set a variable using the value of another variable. Basically something like below:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\newVar}{\pgfmathifthenelse{\oldVar==0}{(\x/2)}{\x}}
```

But no matter what I do I can't seem to get the syntax right. I'm assuming it has something to do with expanding stuff, but can't figure out what is and isn't needing to be expanded. I can't find anything on this that makes sense. All the ones I've seen use the if/then to actually output things rather than set them as variables. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\pgfmathifthenelse` is the standalone version that writes the result to `\pgfmathresult`, setting macro needs the inline math function evaluated such as

```
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\newVar}{ifthenelse(\oldVar==0,(\x/2),\x)}
```

or shorter

```
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\newVar}{(\oldVar==0?(\x/2):\x)}.
```